How to get dropdown list in edit action .NET Core?
I am trying to display the selected value in the dropdown when call the Edit action. Currently my code displays the following in dropdown list. The value does get display with the @Html method
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Projectname)

However what I am trying to achieve is that should be able bring the selected value with the dropdown list. I did try to store the dropdown list in a ViewBag, but it displays WebDSR.Models.DTO.Project.
Instead it should display the project name - the values from database as selected
Amazon
Walmart 
Myntra

Controller action method:
public IActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    ViewBag.Project = new SelectList(db.Defects
                                       .Where(x => x.DefectId == id)
                                       .Select(x => new Project() { ProjectId = x.ProjectId, ProjectName = x.ProjectName}));
    return View(db.Defects.Find(id));
}

View
<select asp-items="ViewBag.Project" class="form-control"></select>

Any help is much appreciated.

I recommend you do the selecting in the controller and passing the data in a model, no need to use ViewBag. What is the content of ViewBag.Project if you set a breakpoint?

Do you mean to select the value after user selects an item and post back the page? Or you mean to select a default value the first time the page is shown?

Probably you are missing @ to refer the variable in Razor page. <select asp-items="@ViewBag.Project" class="form-control"></select>

Since you are providing the IEnumerable list of your model class type instead of IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, you need to specify the properties names for the option value and label according to SelectList(IEnumerable, String, String).
ViewBag.Project = new SelectList(
    db.Defects
        .Select(x => new Project() { ProjectId = x.ProjectId, ProjectName = x.ProjectName }),
    nameof(Project.ProjectId),
    nameof(Project.ProjectName)
);

In the Razor page, you are missing the @ to refer to the ViewBag.Project.
@model YourModel

<select asp-items="@ViewBag.Project" class="form-control" asp-for="Id"></select>


appreciate your suggestion. I tired above code, it only displays selected value, I wanted it to bring up all other values along with the selected one. How could that be achieved?

Hi @Rezo, updated my answer. 1. You should not apply the filtering .Where() for the defects, instead, you should return all the records from Defects DBSet. 2. You can use the asp-for attribute, thus it will select the matching option based on the Id property.

Thank you again, dropdown appears with other select options, but it should be default to the one already selected instead of wrong selection. Example: value in db = Amazon, so when we load Edit action, drop down should have Amazon as selected and followed by the other select options.

If you use asp-for attribute, the select dropdown will auto select the option based on Id. I can't know what is your Defect class, could be due to the reference property in asp-for is incorrect. Either you need to try asp-for="DefectId" based on what I see in the controller or please share your model class in the question. Thanks.

Thank you, here is what I did. public IEnumerable ListProject { get; set; } set selectlist in the model class. In controller passed list in model instead of ViewBag like this model.ListProject  = logic, and finally called list in View using ID as you suggested. and it worked. Thank you.

Just one more thing,how can we perform same action but not in EDIT Action but where we list full listing in View. Can this be achieved.

Great, this works in List view aswell, but had to pass data in ViewBag instead of MODEL
